# What are the advantages of strings and character arrays being different?

Tags: c, strings, arrays, characters

In many languages such as Java, strings and character arrays are distinct types. In Java one must use `toCharArray()` in order to use array semantics on strings.

In C, strings and character arrays are more or less the same. A C string is just a character array with a null terminator. Otherwise there is no internal distinction between them.

What are the advantages or disadvantages of strings being distinct types from character arrays?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Separate string methods or going via arrays

A disadvantage of a string type is that the methods available to manipulate arrays cannot just be used for strings. Instead, the language must either provide a separate set of functionality (which means more to document, learn, etc.) or force the programmer to split a string into an array whenever character manipulations are needed.

Array programming languages like APL, J, and K, make extensive use of array functions to manipulate strings, with great effect.

Comment: Ideally I'd like a string _not_ to share methods with an array. What is `"\U0001F1F8\u200d\U0001F1FA".map(println)` supposed to do? Query the OS' default font to figure it out at runtime?

Comment: @Longinus I'd expect it to loop over Unicode codepoints. That's what [Scala does](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/ltLr73CJRxqE6lOQWeQu4Q).

Comment: @user That would break any text editor GUI using that code.

Comment: @Longinus I don't see why it would. A text editor specifically working with Unicode would use a separate method that's aware of the fact that the "array" passed into it is really a string in UTF-8 or whatever, to be displayed in a specific font.

Comment: @user Unless you are implementing a compiler for a particular system, Unicode is the default, not a specificity the user should give particular care to enable. And the Standard defers the meaning of `"\U0001F1F8\u200d\U0001F1FA"` to the ISO 3166 Maintenance Agency which observes _geopolitics_. To ascribe some other API behaviour requires you to ignore ISO. Also why the Standard says a "character" is "what the user sees."

Comment: @Longinus That is true, but I don't see what stops you from making a method that works on arrays of `Character`s with the same behavior as a method working on strings in a language with a separate string type

Comment: @user We can, but when `map`ping over an `Array<T>` we know we deal with `T`s, whereas when `map`ping over a `String`, nothing tells us what we're actually doing - code units? Code points? Graphemes? Grapheme clusters? Glyphs? Composed emojis? Emoji components? ZWJ sequence components? All of which fit one of the **many** definitions of the word "character" - so I don't think we should. Also whether one option is more "obvious" than another depends on whether you're dealing with text (which is graphical) or memory (which is not).

Comment: As a counter-example, C++ has string types that can be manipulated using the `<algorithm>` functions that work equally well on arrays or other containers.  (Yes, C++ strings are somewhat limited in that they tend to hold only a single codepoint at each position, but the language would allow a more sophisticated grapheme-cluster representation to be implemented and still satisfy the Container interface.)

Comment: @Longinus I wrote an answer that gives some focus to this issue. Would appreciate any additional technical insights.

Answer (score 17):

## Different definitions of “character”

In Swift, the `Character` type isn’t a single Unicode codepoint (that’s `UnicodeScalar`), nor is it a single byte (that’s `CChar`). Instead, it represents an “extended grapheme cluster”, which includes combining diacritics. This makes some things more straightforward — `é` is one Unicode codepoint and `é` is two, but they’re both a single character. However, it means that characters aren’t a fixed size, and for `String` to just be `[Character]` would be a massive waste of memory. Don’t get me wrong, it is a `Collection<Character>`, just not a random-access collection the way an array is.

Answer (score 9):

An array must have a fixed stride, so that the memory address of the *i*th element equals the address of the start of the array plus *i* times the stride. If you really want an array of *characters*, so that each logical character (i.e. each Unicode symbol) occupies one slot in the array, then the array's stride would need to be 32 bits.

That is a waste of space compared to UTF-8 encoding, in which the most common characters take 8 or 16 bits each. On the other hand, if you encode strings as UTF-8 then it's no longer true that the *i*th character occurs at a predictable index, so what you have is not an array of characters. (Instead, it is an array of bytes, but that's the internal implementation ─ the API need not expose it to the user as such.)

Comment: _Technically_, you only need 21 bits. That doesn't exactly optimize well, though, as loading an odd number of bits is even worse than a regular unaligned load.

Comment: A "Unicode symbol" can be more than 32bits. National flags are 64bits, and both combining characters and ZWJ sequences allow for "symbols" to be arbitrarily long.

Comment: A Unicode *code point* must be between 0 and 0x10FFFF, hence "21 bits".  It's true that a user-perceived "character" can contain multiple code points, though.

Comment: Arrays cannot have a stride of 21 bits; it would be rounded up to 32.

Comment: @Longinus To my knowledge, the national flag symbols are not "Unicode symbols" ─ they are "individual symbols" because applications render them as such, but Unicode doesn't define them as far as I know. Really they are sequences of Unicode symbols which are interpreted as national flags by convention rather than by the Unicode standard.

Comment: @kaya3-supportthestrike Unicode describes national flags as "components" of "emojis," and all emojis as "symbols." Then, TR51 explicitly mentions that there are concurrent ways to "count emojis" including delegating work to the system's font and the fact that this is a platform-specific problem.

Comment: @kaya3-supportthestrike Would 24 be possible? Or do arrays of three-byte objects (e.g., a tuple of `i8`s or an `Option<i16>`) get rounded up to 32 for some sort of alignment reason?

Comment: Why can't arrays have a stride of 21 bits?  That seems quite reasonable on hardware that has a 7-bit word size (obviously that's one that can't run C, but we haven't chosen our target yet).

Comment: @TobySpeight but if we are considering impractical and/or theoretical machines, why do we still care about the Unicode standard?

Comment: @Karl,  I'm merely referring to [5.2.4.2.1](https://web.archive.org/web/20181230041359if_/http%3a//www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf#subsection.5.2.4), which specifies that `CHAR_BIT` must be at least 8.  BTW, that doesn't mean that these older machines are necessarily _impractical_, but that that their implementation of C needs a little care.

Comment: I understood what you meant by "can't run C" (as you clarify, need special considerations in order to run C). My point is that 21-bit strides make no sense on *ordinary* hardware *in common use* that follow contemporary *standards*; and if those standards and expectations are out the window, then I don't see why respecting the Unicode standard would still be important.

Comment: This discussion is all moot; even if you had an exotic CPU architecture where a character array could have a stride of 21 bits, it would still be a waste of space compared to a string encoded in UTF-8 where most characters take only 8 or 16 bits. The conclusion of the answer still holds.

Answer (score 7):

## Handling Encoding

Arrays of raw data don't, generally speaking, have an encoding. Strings can be in UTF-8 or any number of other formats. In Ruby, a `String` object is an array of bytes together with its `Encoding`. If you're handling data in different formats (such as data coming in from the network and then entering your main program's file system or database), it can be invaluable having the language keep track of this for you.

Comment: In Dyalog APL, there are only character arrays, but they *are* stored with their encoding, namely 1-, 2-, or 4-byte unsigned integer Unicode code points.

Answer (score 7):

### Resizing with Bounds Checking and Constant-Time Size Lookup

The most common alternatives do not have all three.  A fixed-length array is not resizable.  And C-style arbitrary-length, null-terminated strings are the biggest bug attractor in history.  Anyone reading this far down on this site knows why.

It’s also faster on modern vector CPUs to copy or scan a memory range whose length is known in advance than to search for the terminating character.

### Short-String Optimization

Most strings are short (less than 32 bytes or so), and `String` implementations almost always optimize them so they can be statically-allocated, and not use the heap.

Standard libraries want this optimization to be transparent, and they do *not* want this optimization for a generic `Vector`, which would meet the first three requirements.

### Variable-Width Encodings

Several other answers have mentioned this, but the specific problem with making a `String` an array of `Char` is that arbitrary indexing of a variable-width encoding is both unsafe and useless.  It might point to a location that is a UTF-8 continuation byte or UTF-16 surrogate (or, previously, turn Shift-JIS into mojibake).

Changing arbitrary bytes could produce an invalid string.  Even the “wide-character strings” that were promised to be fixed-width in the ’90s have turned out not to be.  The C and C++ standards could say how wide strings “MUST” be a fixed-width encoding all they wanted.  It didn’t get Microsoft to break the Windows API.  They made their wide encoding variable-width anyway, and that was that.

Even changing one codepoint in the middle of a string to another valid codepoint could force the entire tail of the string to shift in memory, a linear-time operation that might even force the entire string to be reallocated and invalidate all current pointers to its data, so using array notation for replacing characters with other characters is actively misleading about the semantics.

It would be possible to use arrays of UCS-4, but that wastes too much memory when storing English, and often the user will want to iterate over graphemes instead of codepoints anyway.  Some implementations add “breadcrumbs” (the offsets of the characters at certain positions within the string) to speed up linear-time operations, which also requires a special type.

### Validation

Related to the above, a blob of character data is not necessarily a valid Unicode string.  And in some languages, it’s common to use strings as blobs of arbitrary bytes of data.  But if a `String` class validates its input, the type system can guarantee that any `String` object always contains a valid string.  It could also perform normalization, if desired.  Some algorithms run faster on canonically-decomposed Unicode.

### Arrays are a Leaky Abstraction

If you look at the history of the C++ `std::string`, you see it starting out trying to offer implementers some flexibility.  That didn’t work, because the API exposed a pointer to the bytes of a C-style, null-terminated array of `char`.

So, it became official: `std::string` *must* be implemented that way.  It could not, for example, be a rope, because it must be laid out in memory as a single contiguous array with random access.  It could not be a copy-on-write class, because writing through a pointer within the array doesn’t invalidate pointers to the data.  It could not save a byte of memory by removing the redundant terminating null when it already stored the length, because you had to be able to pass the address of the first `char` to a function that expected a C-style `char*`.

A class that did a better job of hiding its implementation details would have much more freedom to implement something stringy in a way that suits the application better.

Comment: `It didn’t get Microsoft to break the Windows API. They made their wide encoding variable-width anyway, and that was that.` I'm no MS fan but this is not the sequence of events as I recall it. It actually took MS an annoyingly long time to switch Windows from UCS-2 to UTF-16. It looks like you're suggesting they forced that change on everyone else. If I'm wrong please point me somewhere I can read up and learn.

Comment: @hippietrail All I’m saying is that their switching `wchar_t` from UCS-2 to UTF-16 ignored the part of the Standard that said `wchar_t` must be a fixed-width encoding. The Windows API was defined back when UCS-2 was, and MS refused to make breaking changes, but this meant that `wchar_t`  became a variable-width encoding on Windows. This made all code that uses `wchar_t` non-portable, and not all compilers support `std::ctype<char32_t>`.

Answer (score 4):

### Encapsulation

Treating strings as character arrays entails a belief that a character array is an adequate *model for* a string - not just good enough now, but good enough that you won't want to be able to swap it out later while keeping existing interfaces.

In reality, there are many operations on strings that don't make a lot of sense on character arrays, and vice-versa. It's questionable, for example, whether strings should provide random access at all. If you index into a string, should this produce a "character" that is an instance of a separate type? What should one be able to **do with** that object? Different languages have different answers to this question.

Another problem is that characters are completely different from *graphemes*. Consider this Python example:

```python
>>> 'fiancée'[::-1]
'eécnaif'
>>> 'fiancée'[::-1]
'éecnaif'
```

The first string uses a precomposed character to represent the grapheme é with a single code point:

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.name('fiancée'[-2])
'LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE'
```

The second "composes" the symbol using two separate characters:

```
>>> unicodedata.name('fiancée'[-2])
'COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT'
>>> unicodedata.name('fiancée'[-3])
'LATIN SMALL LETTER E'
```

There are much stranger phenomena than that:

```python
>>> calendars = "️" + ""
>>> len(calendars)
3
```

**Depending on your environment**, the two calendars might look the same or different - for me, they are different in my browser, but the same in my terminal. The length is `3` because the first one is composed of two characters: the calendar emoji followed by a "variation selector". There isn't a "precomposed version" of that; the variation selector is something like a control character that tells the text engine to draw a different glyph (image) for the previous character, while still treating it as the same character.

It is left as a (hopefully simple) exercise to explain why `calendars[::-1]` will produce a result that looks the same as `calendars`, regardless of the environment.

Don't even get me *started* on the [bidirectional text layout algorithm and associated control codes](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr9/). You understood correctly: the people responsible for standardizing Unicode are currently on revision 46 of a document about 18 thousand words long just to explain *how to decide when to write text left to right and when to write it right to left*.

But, sure, reversing a string is a toy problem that also turns out not to be very important in realistic applications. What about the real meat and potatoes of string manipulation?

- Did you know that some languages have a concept of uppercase and lowercase, but don't have separate uppercase and lowercase versions of every letter? For example, the [German letter ß](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9F) is considered lowercase; when a word containing it is set in uppercase, the ß is supposed to be replaced with SS (two uppercase Ses)? So it's not actually possible to uppercase words in a locale-aware way by simply iterating over characters and replacing them separately. The length of the string might need to change. I'm not even sure that each character can be considered independently, for every language.
- Did you know that many widely-used written languages are only ever intended to appear in a "cursive" form (i.e. there are strokes that visually continue between letters), so there are corresponding variant characters with different appearances (assigned separate code points - not distinguished with variation selectors - perhaps because they had to solve the problem before anyone came up with the idea of variation selectors)? Did you know that you might be expected to substitute the glyphs from those variant characters to render a string, while still treating the string as being composed of whatever was actually put into it? And, if you're the poor sap tasked with implementing text rendering for an operating system, you might be expected to ensure that the characters have their variant appearances when selected, but copying and pasting them gives the original "general" characters?

  ```python
  >>> # Try highlighting, copying and pasting individual letters of the output.
  >>> # (You might find it tricky because of the LTR rendering.)
  >>> print('\u0628\u0628\u0628')
  ببب
  ```
- Did you know that the order in which people expect strings to be sorted, is not necessarily based on Unicode code point order at all? And that it might be different for different languages (that could validly have the same two strings in them)? And that it might not be possible to apply naive lexicographical ordering at all (i.e. considering the first character first, breaking ties with the second character etc.)? And that this will get completely broken by combining characters anyway? And that you can't actually necessarily determine the language of text just by examining some characters (`chat` can validly be an English verb or a French noun)? And that there's a [whole other essay](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr10/) on Unicode.org about how to do it properly? (About 30 thousand words, by the way.)
- Did you know that for the East Asian languages that use ideographs and/or logographs (Chinese, Japanese and [occasionally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanja) Korean - and even [Vietnamese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ch%E1%BB%AF_H%C3%A1n), which I didn't know before writing this answer), Unicode provides ["unified" characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Unified_Ideographs) - such that a symbol might be considered "the same character" in different languages, but is supposed to be displayed differently depending on what language is being written? And that you can't rely on variation selectors to tell you which glyph to use? (And, again, for short excerpts, you can't reliably determine the language by examining the characters - after all, it often takes only a single character to express an entire word/concept?) And that the [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_unification) of doing this was an absolute ton of work, and the results are still contentious in some places? And that sometimes "traditional Chinese" characters and their "simplified Chinese" counterparts use the same code point (as in the table at the previous link), and [sometimes they're separate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplified_Chinese_characters)?

  - And that the entire topic can be *really politically sensitive*?
- Did you know that the text in a string could be in more than one language? That it could be in [*no* languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dingbat)? That it could try to [express an idea, despite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji) not consisting of words in a language? That it could try to express an idea that [isn't linguistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_Symbols_(Unicode_block))? That it could try to [decorate meaningful text with meaningless symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zalgo_text)?
- Did you know about [the hack used to cram the Unicode code space into 16-bit encodings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Character_Set_characters#Surrogates)? (Or, relatedly, the reason why the allowed number of distinct code points *isn't a power of 2*?)

Text is **really, really** complicated. Attempting to model it as merely an *array* of characters is hopefully naive. While, yes, it is conceptually composed of a sequence of characters (in the only models of it we have that are viable to work with on computers), it makes next to no sense to expose a plain array interface to that sequence (whether or not mutable). Arrays have the conceptual affordance of algorithms that just don't work on text.

---

This stands *completely independent* of the question of whether a *byte* is an adequate model for a *character*. Yes, it's true that UTF-8 uses a varying number of bytes to encode each character, such that a string implementation relying on a storage buffer in UTF-8 encoding could not be random access. But this is an absolutely *trifling* issue compared to ones created by naive ideas about what a "character" actually is, and about how text is written, and about what manipulations make sense for that data.

Sure, we have a standard that precisely, unambiguously and permanently maps abstract numbers to "characters". We have a virtual "code space" for those numbers, a commitment not to ever reassign them even if it would make things look much more elegant, and a reasonable assurance that we won't overflow that space for a very, very long time, even as we strain to come up with bizarre pseudo-textual things to fill that space with.

And, sure, there are many plausible ways to represent "a character", depending on system requirements:

- A byte whose values correspond to the first 256 Unicode code points (obviously restricted to text that only uses those characters)
- A byte whose values are mapped to Unicode code points in an instance-specific manner, according to encoding metadata stored along with the array (restricted to text that only uses characters from one of such single-byte encodings - which can only exist for languages that fit in such a character limit, and don't deal well with mixed-language text)
- An unsigned 16-bit value representing a Unicode code point from the [Basic Multilingual Plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane) (only represents those characters - so no emoji, very limited ideographic support, many world languages missing, no [private use area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas))
- The same, but using surrogate pairs to represent characters outside the BMP
- An 32-bit value, which might as well be signed I suppose
- A 21-bit value, bit-packed three to each 64-bit machine word (now that 64-bit architectures are the norm)

And, sure, there might not be any need to use a linked list, or other data structure, to store the underlying character data. Simply writing each character's corresponding number sequentially in memory - i.e., using an array - is perfectly adequate for the simple task of remembering which characters are in the string, in what order.

But... **none of these things actually address the fundamental complexity of text**. While it's easy to laugh at the previous generation of Western programmers and their naive faith placed in "code pages", the "array" part of "array of characters" is also problematic - perhaps much more so.

Exposing such an interface to the raw storage raises many questions. Simply equating the string type with an array-of-characters type - leaving all that string functionality outside the type itself - causes innumerable problems. Please don't do it in your language.

Comment: +1000 Excellent answer addressing the (huge) gap from arrays to human language text. And you didn't even get to normalization. :-)

Comment: Although I didn't explicitly mention normalization, I touch on it in a few places.

Answer (score 2):

## Performance

In Java, a char array can be expensive. If what we need is a pure ASCII string, then using a char array will waste most of the memory. We may want to use a byte array, but it's not the same type as char arrays.

## Encodings

In Java, strings are stored in UTF-16 encoding, but it is explicitly known by all users. If we use a char array, it's less clear which encoding it is using.

Answer (score 2):

If Java had included a family of immutable-array and immutable-array-segment types, each with a constructor that could accept a single array (mutable or not) and construct an immutable array (copying the data if the original was mutable), a constructor that could accept an array of arrays (mutable or not) and produce a composite immutable array, and a factory method to produce an immutable array segment from an immutable array, then it would make sense to use immutable arrays and array segments of `char` to represent strings.  Having an immutable string type is extremely useful in a language that's based around a tracing garbage collector, and if there are no other immutable array types, making strings immutable would make it necessary for them to be distinct from other array types.

Note that in scenarios where an immutable array of `char`, `short`, or `int` would often not contain any values outside the range of a signed or unsigned byte, it may be worthwhile to store instances meeting that criterion using one byte per element.  Code using elements of such arrays would be more complicated, but the reduction in cache footprint would often overcome that disadvantage.

Answer (score 1):

> In C, strings and character arrays are more or less the same. A C string is just a character array with a null terminator. Otherwise there is no internal distinction between them.

The only distinction between a string and a character array is whether the data is handled as a scalar or not.

C basically handles all strings usually as variable-length arrays, and C has so little facility for working with VLAs that its treatment of strings (whilst very simple to grasp in principle) tends to be regarded as hard work compared to more modern languages.

> What are the advantages or disadvantages of strings being distinct types from character arrays?

Alternatively put, you are asking *what is the advantage of arrays being treated as scalars?*

The advantage of treating arrays as scalars is that you don't have to treat everything constantly as an array of bits! The bit being the only fundamental scalar in computing, with everything else being an array of bits.

The main problem with strings is that they tend to be variable length. Other bit arrays which are treated as scalars - like integers - were reducible to fixed-width forms at a relatively early stage of electronic computing, so that all *hardware* treats them as scalars even. Never so with strings, not even today.

At the time of C's design, and still today, there isn't a well worked-out scheme for how type systems cope with arrays in a fully general, systematic, and happy manner.

Even in APL, where arrays are king (and already were in 1972), the problem is solved largely by dispensing with types and a variety of other extravagances which make it completely unsuitable to the same purposes as C.

Nevertheless, most languages more modern than C, have implemented some kind of special treatment for string types and for operators which manipulate strings as if they are scalars, because there aren't any disadvantages to being able to treat strings as scalars, none whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Java strings are immutable, making possible to share them. But this is very bad for security, as data like passwords may stay in the memory for very long with no way to clear them. Due that, character arrays must be used for all sensitive data that are discarded (overwritten) asap after using them. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881291/why-is-char-preferred-over-string-for-passwords) for more on this topic.

Immutable strings also mean that a new string is created each time you modify it. A heavily multi-threaded applications avoided touching the heap as much as possible because the new object allocation scales very badly with the number of threads: the memory pool is shared and all access there must be synchronized. I had applications where adding more threads after the first 20 or about actually brought the performance down, even if it was on the 64 core high performance computer.

Comment: "Due that, character arrays must be used for all sensitive data that are discarded asap after using them." Explicitly cleared, not necessarily "discarded" (i.e. abandoned to the garbage collector, which will only "deallocate" memory but not actually make it unreadable). On the other hand, this is only important in a context where an attacker can already read process memory. Also, last I checked the String type is still immutable (it would be a huge, breaking change), it's just that there are also other textual types that aren't.

Comment: It is commonly seen as a security flaw to use strings for passwords in Java. Please read the provided source for details.